# KnockoutJS: How to run script after inserting data in observable array

Tags: javascript, data-binding, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have a gallery list:

```
 <div class="gallery">
            <a href="#" class="next">next</a>
            <a href="#" class="prev">prev</a>

            <div class="frame">
                <ul data-bind="foreach: designs">
                    <li>
                        <span class="text">№<span data-bind="text: getID()"></span> <span data-bind="text: getName()"></span></span>
                         <img src="images/img01.jpg" width="182" height="102" alt="image description"/>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

  </div>
```

**JS**

```
Models.Design = function () {...}

function ViewModel(){   
    this.designs = ko.observableArray();


    this.addDesign = function (_id, _name, _image, _video) {

        var design = new Models.Design;

        design.setID(_id);
        design.setName(_name);

        this.designs.push(design);
   };

   this.addDesign(1, "Image 1");
   this.addDesign(2, "Image 1");
   this.addDesign(3, "Image 1");
 // at this moment there is no elements in DOM
}
```

**Question:** Where need i write `$('.gallery').galleryScroll();` for update my gallery slider?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just subscribe to the observable. Your callback will be invoked for any visible* changes to the collection.

```
function ViewModel() {
    this.designs = ko.observableArray();
    this.designs.subscribe(function () {
        $('.gallery').galleryScroll();
    });

    // ...
}
```

* Visible meaning you perform operations on the observable, not directly on the underlying array.

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.gallery = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(element).parents('.gallery').galleryScroll();
        });
    }
};

 <ul data-bind="foreach: designs, gallery:{}">
     <li>....</li>
 </ul>
```